# Is there a way to write into python code a command to include duplicate entries into a My SQL database

Tags: python, sql

I have to write up a python program that communicates with a My SQL database to write in data... I have done the code however it does not enter all the data as it says there are duplicates... is there a way to just inclue them?

Comment: ...or if the question is about removing duplicates from a data structure e.g. a list, `set()` is one way forward... Q is a bit unclear

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information like you SQL and database schema. It sounds like you are trying to insert items with the same primary key. If you remove the primary key you should be able to insert the data, or change the insert statement to not insert the field which is the primary key.